# MP4Box shell script not working

Tags: shell, mp4box

I am trying to use MP4Box to concatenate several .mp4 files in a directory. The basic command in a simple form looks like this:

```
mp4box -cat 'Film.mp4' -cat 'Credits.mp4' -new Total.mp4
```

I made this script, but it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash
files='*.mp4'; for i in $files; do MP4Box -cat "'"$i"'" -new Total.mp4; done
```

It just gives:

```
Error appending '01_Introduction.mp4': Requested URL is not valid or cannot be found
Error - 2 input names specified, please check usage
Error - 2 input names specified, please check usage
Error - 2 input names specified, please check usage
Error - 2 input names specified, please check usage
Error - 2 input names specified, please check usage
Error - 2 input names specified, please check usage
... etc.
```

What is wrong with my expression?

I settled with:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm Total.mp4; files='*.mp4'; for i in $files; do
echo " -cat " "'"$i"'" >>input.txt; done

file="input.txt"; name=$(cat "$file"); 

eval "MP4Box " $name " -new Total.mp4";
```

Comment: Why are you trying to stuff single quotes around the expanded file name? You don't want them. Just use `"$i"` as the filename.

Comment: add `set -x` before your `for` loop, and `set +x` after the `done`. (shell debug/trace). You'll see that MP4box is being executed for each file in `*.mp4` rather than buiding up one command to execute at the same time. Good luck.

Comment: I used the single quotes because the file names have spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled with:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm Total.mp4; files='*.mp4'; for i in $files; do
echo " -cat " "'"$i"'" >>input.txt; done

file="input.txt"; name=$(cat "$file"); 

eval "MP4Box " $name " -new Total.mp4";
```